# Is there an alternative to python's permutations for generator input?

Tags: python, generator, permutation, python-itertools, infinite

I am trying to use an unbounded generator in `itertools.permutations` but it doesn't seem to be working. The return generator is never created because the function just runs forever. To understand what I mean, consider:

```
from itertools import count, permutations
all_permutations = permutations(count(1), 4)
```

How I imagine this working is that it generates all possible 4-length permutations of the first 4 natural numbers. Then it should generate all possible 4-length permutations of the first 5 natural numbers, with no repeats so 5 must be included in all of these. What happens though is that python is hung on creating `all_permutations`.

Before I go off and create my own function from scratch, I am wondering if there is another library that might be able to do what I'm looking for? Also, shouldn't the built-in function here be able to handle this? Is this perhaps a bug that should be worked out?

EDIT: For some iterations...

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 4 3
...
4 3 2 1
1 2 3 5
1 2 5 3
...
5 3 2 1
1 2 4 5
1 2 5 4
...
```

Comment: The ordering guarantees provided by `itertools.permutations` don't make sense for an infinite input, so it's really no surprise that `itertools.permutations` doesn't support infinite inputs.

Comment: let's try from the opposite: post the expected output reflecting several consecutive operations (how should it look?)

Comment: I threw some up there for you. I would have to go pretty far out to see the subtleties, but you get the idea. Also, it doesn't have to be in that exact order, I would just like to get the permutations so I can cycle through them.

Comment: (If `itertools.permutations` *did* support infinite input, the ordering guarantees would force it to output `(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 5), (1, 2, 3, 6), (1, 2, 3, 7), ...` without ever reaching a permutation that doesn't begin with `1, 2, 3`.)

Comment: You are gonna need an unbounded amount of memory to do this, because you have to remember every item forever

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice question! Here's an efficient method that generates them systematically, without repetitions (and without any need to check):

1. First the permutations of the first `n` elements;
2. then the permutations **involving the `n+1`st element** and `n-1` of the previous ones;
3. then those involving the `n+2`nd element and `n-1` of the previous ones, etc.

In other words, the last element drawn is always included in the current batch. This only keeps around a tuple of the consumed source elements (unavoidable, since we'll keep using all of them in permutations).

As you can see, I simplified the implementation a little: Instead of step 1, I initialize the `base` with `n-1` elements and go straight to the main loop.

```
from itertools import islice, permutations, combinations

def step_permutations(source, n):
    """Return a potentially infinite number of permutations, in forward order"""

    isource = iter(source)
    # Advance to where we have enough to get started
    base = tuple(islice(isource, n-1))

    # permutations involving additional elements:
    # the last-selected one, plus <n-1> of the earlier ones
    for x in isource:
        # Choose n-1 elements plus x, form all permutations
        for subset in combinations(base, n-1):
            for perm in permutations(subset + (x,), n):
                yield perm

        # Now add it to the base of elements that can be omitted 
        base += (x,)
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> for p in step_permutations(itertools.count(1), 3):
    print(p)

(1, 2, 3)
(1, 3, 2)
(2, 1, 3)
(2, 3, 1)
(3, 1, 2)
(3, 2, 1)
(1, 2, 4)
(1, 4, 2)
(2, 1, 4)
(2, 4, 1)
(4, 1, 2)
(4, 2, 1)
(1, 3, 4)
(1, 4, 3)
(3, 1, 4)
(3, 4, 1)
(4, 1, 3)
(4, 3, 1)
(2, 3, 4)
(2, 4, 3)
(3, 2, 4)
...
```

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same as the algorithm I already showed?

Comment: Not the original one. I see you have a new algorithm, is it the same you think?

Comment: In a sense they would _have_ to be similar, since there's only one clean way to introduce the new elements. But our implementations are pretty different, I think.

Comment: Same idea implemented slightly differently (it makes them in a different order).   +1 anyway.

Comment: As I said in my other comments here, not only is this more similar to the order that I didn't care about, but by using `timeit` on code to generate a list of the first 10**6 elements of both answers I found this is about twice as fast. Good job!

Comment: Interesting, I don't think either of us was concerned about speed-- just non-redundancy and a nice algorithm.  Anyway thanks for choosing my answer. The speed difference is probably due to using `permutations()` instead of building lists by hand. I'm sure you can shave off a few percent more here and there.

Comment: This is faster because one pure Python loop gets replaced with a loop in C implementation (assuming you have the itertools code imported from the .so file).  You can make it about 15% faster again by replacing that inner loop with `yield from permutations(subset + (x,), n)`.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
from itertools import count, permutations

def my_permutations(gen, n=4):
    i = iter(gen)
    population = []
    seen = set()
    while True:
        for p in permutations(population, n):
            if p not in seen:
                yield p
                seen.add(p)
        population.append(next(i))
```

Beware, the memory usage is growing forever, but as far as I can see there is no way around that.

More efficient version:

```
def my_permutations(gen, n=4):
    i = iter(gen)
    population = []
    while True:
        population.append(next(i))
        *first, last = population
        perms = permutations(first, n-1)
        yield from (p[:i] + (last,) + p[i:] for p in perms for i in range(n))
```

Comment: There's no need to keep a `seen` set; you can just check `population[-1] in p`.

Comment: Actually you don't need to check at all.  You know you must take population[-1] element.  Like I said, it can be made more efficient.

Comment: You wouldn't need to check if you were generating the permutations yourself, but if you're delegating to `itertools.permutations`, `itertools.permutations` doesn't know it needs to pick that element.

Comment: No, you misunderstand me.  You have to use `permutations(population[:-1], n-1)` and then slot in the new element in every possible position.

Comment: Yeah, by changing the generation mechanism, you can avoid the need to filter. That particular way of changing the generation mechanism also changes the result order, but the questioner has said the order isn't too important.

Comment: Looking at the two answers so far, I'd have to say this is the better one. If order was important, then the answer alexis gave would be better, as that has the order I gave. However (and I probably should've put more importance on this in the question), order is not important and speed is much more important in this particular case. I did some testing and found that in order to generate the first 10**6 iterations with count(), this took 0.000633979 s whereas alexis' took 0.899549 s. This discrepancy makes me think theres something wrong with my timing it, but thats what I got.

Comment: Sorry, that was using a line-by-line analyzer. I think theres something throwing it off with this particular code. By using the builtin timeit, I get alexis' method is faster (0.32s vs 0.65s).